# Proving Expected Value

Tags: calculus, statistics

Prove that

$$E[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X(x))\,dx -  \int_{-\infty}^0 F_X(x)\,dx$$

I am guessing I need to have $f'(x)$ somewhere in here?

How can I start?

Comment: Clarification:

F = CDF
f= PDF

Comment: You say that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but the statement to prove makes no mention of $Y$.  Is this intentional?  Also, I assume that $F_{X}$ is the cdf (cumulative distribution function) of $X$ - is that correct?

Comment: Why would you need that $X$ and $Y$ are independent to find $E[X]$?

Comment: Unwidsom

Yes correct and for the Y sorry forgot to erase.

Comment: Anyways back to the question
I thought the formula for the expected value is 
integral of 1 - F(x) part, but what is the latter part?

Comment: So, what are you trying to do?  You mention something about an "answer", but what is the question?

Comment: @Unwisdom you made my morning.

Comment: The question is to prove the above statement

Comment: So you want to prove that $E[X] = f'(x)$???

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}dx - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_{X}(x)dx = f^{'}(x)$ ?

Comment: @Clarinetist Sorry just forget about the f prime of x, I just began to learn about these concepts please understand. It wants me to prove the main equation stated above

Comment: So you want to prove that $E[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X(x)) \text{ d}x -  \int_{-\infty}^0 F_X(x) \text{ d}x$?

Comment: E[X]=∫∞0(1−FX(x))dx−∫0−∞FX(x)dx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Notice that 
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[X\right] = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X}(x)\text{ d}x &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}xf_{X}(x)\text{ d}x + \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}xf_{X}(x) \text{ d}x\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Try integration by parts on both of these integrals. I suspect that this will give you what you want.

Comment: AWESOME!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Takumi your comment suggests you should mark as the correct answer and up-vote :-)

Comment: I tried, but it is telling me something about reputation TT TT

Comment: @Takumi aw yeah, that. You can still *accept* the answer, regardless of rep.